# exclude button from validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a form with validators and 2 buttons inside form:

```
<input type="submit" class="LFL_btn" value="" />
<input type="image" src="/Content/images/btn_register.jpg" class="LFR_btn" id="btnRegister" />
```

but validator works and for second button too. Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

Because jquery.validate kicks in when you submit a form by hijacking the submit event of this form. And since both are submit buttons, validation is run for both of them.

> how to fix it?

Add `class="cancel"` to the button you want to exclude from validation which will instruct the jQuery.validate plugin not to run validation:

```
<input type="image" src="/Content/images/btn_register.jpg" class="LFR_btn cancel" id="btnRegister" />
<input type="image" src="/Content/images/btn_register.jpg" class="LFR_btn cancel" id="btnRegister" />
```

This has been covered in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Skipping_validation_on_submit).

Obviously all this refers only to client side validation. On the server it's a whole different story. If you wanted to disable validation when some button is clicked you will first need to know which button was clicked. This could happen by giving the first button a `name` attribute and then inspecting on the server the value of this parameter from the request:

```
<button type="submit" class="LFL_btn" name="validate" value="validate">Validate</button>
```

and then inside your controller action check if this button was used to submit the form and apply validation only in this case:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string validate)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validate)) 
    {
        // the Validate button was clicked:
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        if (!TryUpdateModel(model))
        {
            // there were validation errors => redisplay the view
            return View(model);
        }
        // validation went fine => do some processing...
    }
    else
    {
        // the image button was clicked
        // do some other processing ...
    }
}
```